# Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nP(n)/Q(n)}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ be polynomials of the same degree $d>0$. Suppose that the coefficients of the polynomials are nonnegative real numbers. Prove that the series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nP(n)/Q(n)}$$

converges.

I'm pretty stuck here, even in terms of which direction to go. I considered the ratio test, but the algebra is incredibly messy, as would any sort of polynomial long division be.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try applying the euclidean algorithim to $P(n)/Q(n)$ to get that $P(n)/Q(n) = c+\ell(n)$ where $c>0$ and $\ell(n)\in O(n^{-1})$.

Comment: if they have  same  degree, then their ratio approaches to ratio of their  coefficients which corresponds to highest degree  in general,  so  you will have sum of exponential with negative power

Comment: Try the root test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the nth root test! After writing the limit, and bringing the power of $\frac{1}{n}$ inside, the problem turns into a question of when $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}| \exp\big(-\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)} \big)| <1$. Since the argument of the absolute value is always positive, the absolute value can be dropped. It might be worth rewriting the problem as $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{exp \big( \frac{P(n)}{Q(n)} \big)}$ . Since by the way you defined it, $\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}$ will tend to the ratio of the coefficients and that ratio will be positive. Picking the coefficients as you please, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}$ can be made to be arbitrarily large, or arbitrarily close to zero. In any case, $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}| \exp\big(-\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)} \big)|$ will be between, but not including $0$ and $1$. This satisfies convergence by the root test.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$0<\alpha =\lim_{n\to\infty}{P(n)\over Q(n)}$$

which exists and is positive by your assumptions.

Then by the limit comparison test with $b_n= e^{-\alpha n}$ we see your series converges iff

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\alpha n}$$

does. But of course this series converges by integral test.

Comment: Actually that series is a geometric series.

Comment: @zhw. yes this is another way to see it.